# Shared pointer predicate;

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, decltype, multiset

I am really having a hard time understanding these declaration

```
        static bool compare ( const shared_ptr<int> lhs,const shared_ptr<int> rhs )
                    { return (*lhs) < (*rhs) ; }
        multiset<shared_ptr<int>,decltype(compare)*> item{ compare } ;
```

if I dont give pointer after decltype(compare) it gives error? Why error? why should I supply bool* not bool as predicate like algorithm functions, again whats the benifit of giving compare in curly braces in item { compare } ? will it insert objects in multiset in sorted order? if I didnt give the { compare } what would happen?

Comment: Hint: `decltype(compare)` is not the type of the return of a call to `compare`.

Comment: the return type of compare is bool isnt it??

Comment: But the type of `compare` isn't the same as its return type.

Comment: why???? my knowledge is really small.. please explain.

Comment: OK, `compare` is a certain type of static function that returns bool. `decltype(compare)` is the type of that function. `item` is a `multimap` created using `compare` as comparison function to implement the ordering of its elements.

Comment: so , why I compare using bool*, isnt compare is called every time I item.insert(make_shared<int>(x)) and compare the remaining objects. Then it needs bool not a bool* ,, why bool*?

Comment: Because it is not `bool*`, that is what I have been trying to explain. It is `someFunctionType*`, i.e. a pointer to a function.

Comment: thanks.. all the time I have been thinking it as bool* . but then shouldnt I use item { &compare } ; rather than item {compare} ;?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type expected by `multiset` second parameter is a *Predicate*. That is the type of an object `c` such that `c(lhs, rhs)` returns something *convertible to `bool`*.

The type of `compare` and `decltype(compare)` is `bool(shared_ptr<int>, shared_ptr<int>)`, a *function type*. There can't be values of *function type*, but there can be values of *pointers* and *references* to *function types*. That's why you need the `*` there. (Actually, there are values of *function types* and are those things that you declare as functions, but those cannot be created, copied, nor pretty much anything besides calling them and getting their address.) Summing up:

```
decltype(compare)* ==> bool (*)(shared_ptr<int>, shared_ptr<int>)
```

which is a pointer to a function taking two `shared_ptr<int>`s by value and returning a `bool`. Then, in the `multiset` constructor, you give it a value of that type:

```
items{ compare }; // value
```

or more specifically, a value of a *function type* that will *decay* to a function pointer type. So let's make that explicit:

```
items{ &compare }; // pointer to function compare
```

If you didn't give it anything, then it would be a *null pointer*, and when trying to call it to do the comparison your application would crash.

In summary, you chose a hell of a complicated case to go through (and I have skipped a few things I should mention). This is a simpler approach:

```
struct shared_ptr_compare
{
    bool operator()(std::shared_ptr<int> const& lhs, std::shared_ptr<int> const& rhs) const
    { return /*...*/; }
};

multiset<shared_ptr<int>, shared_ptr_compare> item; // no need to initialize 
      // shared_ptr_compare with anything, a default value will do just fine
```

**Note**: I dropped the top-level `const` modifier as it has no effect on a function parameter, it only signals the function body that the values cannot be changed. So it does have meaning, but complicates explaining types.

**Note 2**: You should take those parameters as `shared_ptr<int> const&` (same thing as `const shared_ptr<int>&`), since you do not actually need a copy and those copies have to keep a reference counter which is an operation that has to be synchronized among threads.

Comment: what if the declaration was like this..
     multiset<shared_ptr<int> > item ;
 wont that also insert elements orderly?

Comment: @TamimAdDari it will insert elements based on a different ordering: pointer values, rather than the values of what the pointers point to.